# Post back Errors in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In regular Asp.Net, when you want to post an error, for ex, a duplicate ID, I use Panels for controls, error message labels, etc.  I was wondering, how to achieve the same using MVC 4.

Currently, on my Index page, I have an Id, Name & Address column and a Submit button.  My HTTPPOST ActionResult here:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Person p)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PersonInfo pi = new PersonInfo();

            var duplicate = from d in db.PersonInfoes
                where d.Id == p.Id
                select d;

            if (duplicate.Any())
            {
                return View("Duplicate");
            }
            else
            {....}
```

[image]

When I enter a duplicate Id, upon submitting the page, I need to post to the same view ("Index") page to let user know that there is an Id already, but currently, I am redirecting to a different view to let user know as a duplicate, and I dont think this is the right way to do this.  I am learning MVC, btw and hence this doubt.  My duplicate cshtml here:

```
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Duplicate";
     }

     <h2>Duplicate</h2>

     <h3>Duplicate ID found !!</h3>
     <p>Please correct the ID and re-enter !</p>
     <br/><br/>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to Data Entry","Index")
```

[image]

Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return to the same view. You should consider adding an error to the model state dictionary so that you can show that in the UI.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var duplicate=  db.PersonInfoes.Where(s=>s.Id== p.Id);
      if (duplicate.Any())
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Duplicate found");
         return View(p);
      } 
      // to do : Your existing code
    }
    return View(p);
}
```

Just make sure you are calling the `ValidationSummary` method in your Index view to show this error message.

```
@model Person 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <!-- Your form fields goes here-->
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, seems interesting solution and works, except, i have to figure out how to add the error to the model state dictionary.  Atleast, now without adding it, it posts back to the same view with all the variables in the field..

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Duplicate found");` is how you add the error. Go through the answer carefully again.

Comment: Yes, I added the ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Duplicate found"); before. But now, after your insight, i added @Html.ValidationSummary(false) and now the error shows as Duplicate found.  Thanks a ton, #Shyju, - 1 crossed, 99 million to go now ;)